# How to use/import the NSObject class file in watchExtention?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have added the watchExtention to my existing iPhone project by adding watch target.

> My iPhone app uses the CoreData, I have written NSObject class(DatabaseManagerClass) to
>   manage the CoreData (i.e. Read/Write from database). I want to use
>   that same class in my watch app to manage the same record from
>   database, **Can I do this?**

I tried by importing the "classname.h(DatabaseManagerClass.h)" in "InterfaceController" but it gives error as below

[image]

> I also added the Target for the Class file but same error!
>
> Your help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `UIApplicationDelegate` class in Apple Watch extension as its limited API access in Apple-Watch Extension.

There are 2 ways to fetch core data in appleWatch

1. Fetch data with Shared Data with app group concept.
2. Fetch Data from the iOS app with sending message to iOS app.

> 1st Way :

There are plenty of Blogs which shows step by step implementation how to Fetch core data in Watch

- [WatchKit With Shared CoreData](http://www.makeandbuild.com/blog/post/watchkit-with-shared-core-data)
- [Send Data to Apple Watch](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/send-data-to-apple-watch-with-core-data-and-telerik-ui-for-ios-in-swift)

> 2nd Way:

Now the question is how can we fetch data from `CoreData` and show it on the watch ?

Well, for that you need to communicate your apple watch with iOS app through `WCSession` and send message to iOS app through this class and fetch data in iOS and reply on this message request.

**Follow below steps to get your task done:**

**Step 1:**

Connect your apple watch with iOS through `WCSession`

```
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        self.session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        self.session.delegate = self;
        [self.session activateSession];
        [self.session sendMessage:@{@"GetCoreData":@"YES"} replyHandler:^(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
            //Get Reply Message along with data and use this data in Apple watch
        } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            //Handle error
        }];
    }
}


#pragma mark -- WCSessionDelegate --

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message replyHandler:(void(^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler{

}

- (void)session:(WCSession *)session activationDidCompleteWithState:(WCSessionActivationState)activationState error:(nullable NSError *)error{

}
```

Here in `replyHandler` you will get your data.

**Step 2: Get Connection Over iOS device to receive a message from apple watch.**

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
       _session=[WCSession defaultSession];
       _session.delegate=self;
       [_session activateSession];
}
```

Establish a connection and also add receiver delegate method in your respective class where you need to get Data from DB.

```
    - (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull))replyHandler {

 if ([[message objectForKey:@"OpeniOS"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
     // Fetch your data from DB.


    // After successfully fetching data reply back to Apple watch by reply Block
    replyHandler(<your_data>);
 }
```

}

Based on this you will get your CodeData into your apple watch.

Hope this will helps you to understand the flow.